# Notification window in android becomes all black and unable to see any notification details

Tags: android-notifications

The issue which I am facing is that the notifications are shown on notification bar but when I expand the bar, not able to see the notification details (blank black window is shown).

And if I click on the blank notification window the control goes to the activity for which notification was there.

Can anybody please tell me why is this happening?